# An otherwise workig code raises a KeyError, using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I use the function below to cut matrices based on a set of indexes to keep. I used the part above the line with no problems and I used the bottom part with no problems, but outside of the function, while preparing the original matrix `L` (which is equal to `preL` in this example). I figured I need to recalculate the degree values on the diagonal based on the newly created rows and columns, but now it throws a `KeyError` `1` or `2`, depending on the input (`1` in this example, `2` in my program).

I figured this might be because Once the `mx` is 5x5, I no longer have anything under key = 5, and so I changed each occurence of `range(len(mx))` under the line to `set`. But this resulted in error: `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. What to do?

I read many answers here on Stack and tried to make sense of this but to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd

def matrix_creator(set):
    mx = L.copy()
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if i not in set:
            mx.drop([i], axis=0, inplace=True)
            mx.drop([i], axis=1, inplace=True)

# -------------------------------------------------

    for i in range(len(mx)):
        for j in range(len(mx)):
            if i == j:
                d = 0
                for idx in range(len(mx)):
                    if idx != i:
                        if mx.iloc[i][idx] != 0:
                            d += 1
                mx.iat[i, j] = d

    return mx

preL = [[49.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -6.0, -7.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -6.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -5.0, -1.0, -7.0, -5.0, -2.0, -6.0, -5.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.5, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -4.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -5.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 46.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.5, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0], [-3.0, -3.0, 37.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-6.0, -4.0, -2.0, -1.0, 42.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.5, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-7.0, -3.5, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 40.0, -5.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -5.0, 35.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -6.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -10.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 49.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, 33.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -9.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 34.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 35.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.5, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 35.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 27.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-6.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 39.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -6.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 38.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-5.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -9.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-7.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 42.0, -1.0, -5.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, 53.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.5, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0], [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-6.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -9.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 41.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 40.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 38.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 39.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -9.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, 41.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.0, -5.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.5, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.5, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-4.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.5, -5.0, -10.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0]]


L = pd.DataFrame(preL)

M = matrix_creator([5,6,7,9,10])
print(M)
print(L)
N = matrix_creator([5,9,10])
print(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand your requirement is far easier to achieve with `iloc`

```
import pandas as pd

def matrix_creator(set):
    mx = L.copy()
    mx = mx.iloc[set,set]
    # just return mx if you want index of rows and columns to be as per original matrix
    return mx.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={o:n for n,o in enumerate(mx.columns)})

preL = [[49.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -6.0, -7.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -6.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -5.0, -1.0, -7.0, -5.0, -2.0, -6.0, -5.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.5, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -4.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -5.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 46.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.5, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0], [-3.0, -3.0, 37.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-6.0, -4.0, -2.0, -1.0, 42.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.5, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-7.0, -3.5, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 40.0, -5.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -5.0, 35.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -6.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -10.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 49.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, 33.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -9.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 34.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 35.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.5, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 35.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 27.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-6.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 39.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -6.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 38.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-5.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -9.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-7.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 42.0, -1.0, -5.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, 53.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.5, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0], [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-6.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -9.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 41.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 40.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 38.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 39.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -9.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, 41.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.0, -5.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.5, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.5, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-4.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.5, -5.0, -10.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0]]


L = pd.DataFrame(preL)

M = matrix_creator([5,6,7,9,10])
print(M)
# print(L)
N = matrix_creator([5,9,10])
print(N)
```

**output**

```
      0     1     2     3     4
0  40.0  -5.0  -3.0  -3.0   0.0
1  -5.0  35.0  -3.0  -3.0   0.0
2  -3.0  -3.0  49.0  -3.0  -1.0
3  -3.0  -3.0  -3.0  34.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0  26.0
      0     1     2
0  40.0  -3.0   0.0
1  -3.0  34.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0  26.0
```

Comment: It is much easier to achieve the matrix cut, thanks. But it doesn't solve the problem with altering the diagonal. :(